# How to transform a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, transform

I get the following array in php,

```
[
 {
   Name0: "TEST",
   Value0: "13",
   Timestamp0: "2012-01-02 00:00:13"
 },
{
   Name0: "TEST",
   Value0: "16",
   Timestamp0: "2012-01-02 00:10:45"
 }
],
[
 {
   Name1: "TEST",
   Value1: "30",
   Timestamp1: "2012-01-02 00:00:13"
 },
{
   Name1: "TEST",
   Value1: "60",
   Timestamp1: "2012-01-02 00:10:45"
 }
]
```

and further on,  I want it to be as follows

```
[
 {
   Name0: "TEST",
   Value0: "13",
   Timestamp0: "2012-01-02 00:00:13",
   Name1: "TEST",
   Value1: "30",
   Timestamp1: "2012-01-02 00:00:13"
 },
{
   Name0: "TEST",
   Value0: "16",
   Timestamp0: "2012-01-02 00:10:45",
   Name1: "TEST",
   Value1: "60",
   Timestamp1: "2012-01-02 00:10:45"
 }
]
```

That really crashs my brain with `array_merge` and some other things ;-)
Hope someone can help me here?

Comment: How did you get that result? What are the conditions? Are you trying to combine two consecutive arrays? Or something else? Please be clear.

Comment: I think its not a valid array.

Comment: `$array = $array1+$array2; print_r($array);`

Comment: The first array is an array of arrays:
array(array(values0),array(values1),.....);
Each array entry looks like the one above.
I want to mix these entries into one array
array((values0 and values1),(values0 and values1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general way.

```
$loop_length = count($array[0]);
$new_array = array();
for($i=0; $i<$loop_length; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($array); $j++){
        if(!array_key_exists($j,$new_array)) $new_array[$j] = array();
        $new_array[$j] = array_merge($new_array[$j],$array[$i][$j]);
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through it with the length of `$array[0]`:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++) {
        $array[0][$i] = array_merge($array[0][$i], $array[1][$i]);
    }
    $array = $array[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?php

    $arr1 = array(array('name0' => 'foo', 'val0' => '10'), 
            array('name0' => 'cde', 'val0' => '11'));
    $arr2 = array(array('name1' => 'bar', 'val1' => '20'), 
            array('name1' => 'fgh', 'val0' => '21'));

    $arr_mrg = array();

    for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){
         $arr_mrg[$i] = array_merge($arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
    }

    var_dump($arr_mrg); //test output of the result

?>
```